# How to create 3D wireframe graphic models on Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, 3d, modeling

I’ve some questions that I’ve been trying to solve for awhile and was hoping for some help.

I’ve trying to create 3D wireframe models similar to the attached examples on Illustrator.

Anyone has any method to create them with accuracy and precision?

I have tried the 3D function in illustrator but it does not allow me to control the number of rings or space between each ring.

I would like to be able to control the number and degree of repeat in the model.

Any help would be appreciated!

If there is a better and easier software to use, recommendations are more than welcomed!

Thank you

[image]

[image]

Comment: Would it be ok for you to create these shapes as a series of common shape transformation, completely withou any 3D process? They seem like thay can be created by repeated squishing of the base ±lemniscate 2D shape.

Comment: Why would you use 3d for something thats inherently2D? These are almost certainly 2D as they dont exhibit the cmpression caused by rotation.

Comment: I don't think these are 3D either.  I see nothing more complex than a Step Blend. [See example](https://imgur.com/8pksLMQ)

Comment: Hi Billy, thank you for your comment! I see that I’m probably using the wrong method to achieve this. Would you be willing to show me how you achieved that with a Step Blend? I’m very new to illustrator and any tutorial/advice will be much appreciated!

Comment: I've added an answer now.

Answer (score 7):

These examples don't look 3D to me. Instead, I suspect these were achieved using a "Specified Steps" Blend.

To do this, draw a circle shape, convert one of the anchors to a corner point, select the anchor and move it using the arrow keys on your keyboard. Alt+click and drag the shape to duplicate it, then squish one of the copies so it becomes a vertical line. Select all, apply a Blend, change it to Specified Steps.

Once you have made the blend, Alt+click and drag to duplicate it. Apply a reflect Transform.

Example

[image]